# Can't find page in django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I'm currently learning Django and I'm trying to add form to register a User.

Now my problem starts really early because I get a 404 whenever I try to access my registration page.

My 3 files are as follows:

**views.py** : just a hello world to display basically

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")

def registration(request):
    return HttpResponse("Registration page")
```

**urls.py** (in my project) :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', include('myapp.urls')), # index with login/registration
    (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
    (r'^admin/',  include(admin.site.urls)),  # admin site
)
```

and finally **urls.py** (in my app) :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^registration/$',views.registration, name='registration'),
)
```

When I go to my normal index (localhost:8000) It displays the hello world I wrote in the views.py file. However when I try to go the registration page it just returns me a 404 (localhost:8000/registration).

Now as I said I'm still learning this whole thing, but I don't get why It doesn't work properly. As far as i understand the `r'^$'` in the project file is pointing towards the localhost:8000 and the same regex in the app file tells it to load the index page in this location. Now as the program is still in localhost:8000, a r'^registration/' should be loading the other page in localhost:8000/registration right?

It would be really nice if you could explain to me why this doesn't work and where I did a mistake in my thoughts.

This is the error I get:
[image: Error404]

When i take

```
(r'^randomstringhere/', include('myapp.urls')), # index with login/registration
```

instead of

```
(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')), # index with login/registration
```

I can get to the registration page via localhost:8000/randomstringhere/registration. But Site is meant to have a selection where you can either Log in or register on localhost:8000 (or future domain www.randomdomainhere.com) and a registration/login form on localhost:8000/login, localhost:8000/registration (www.randomdomainhere.com/registration etc.)

Comment: Use a slash in the end: localhost:8000/registration/. At least that's what your regex says for the URL conf. See the answer of Odif Yltsaeb for how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each url you should add a   $   symbol,

```
url(r'^registration/$',views.registration, name='registration'),
```

reffer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

you are missing $ sign in the end of url.

It should be:

```
url(r'^registration/$',views.registration, name='registration'),
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ symbol in django urls means `end-of-string match character` which is borrowed from regular expression. So, $ should be added at the end of your url on app's urls.

```
url(r'^registration/$',views.registration, name='registration'),
```

However we can write urls with the regular expressions that don’t have a $ (end-of-string match character) but we do have to include a trailing slash(/). For urls without $, you must enter the trailing slash while opening the url in your browser to match the regular expression.

Your app urls in project's urls.py is

> url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS

So, to access the registration page, you need to browse by

> localhost:8000/grappelli/registration/

i.e. append the path in your app's url to the path in project's url for the app.

Learn more about urls [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Hmm I tried that before and now again but it didn't work both times. Maybe the mistake is somewhere else... I will add my imports aswell and a screenshot of the 404, but as i can open the standart index page  I don't know if the error is within the imports.

Comment: Well grappelli isn't actually my project^^ It's a Admin theme for django (the admin theme works fine by the way). My problem is, that i'd like to have the "Hello world" on the localhost:8000 and the registration on the localhost:8000/registration. And as far as I understand the `(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')), # index with login/registration` is where it gets the `url(r'^registration/$',views.registration, name='registration'),` from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove $ from the first url as given below

**urls.py (in my project) :**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^', include('myapp.urls')), # index with login/registration
  (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
  (r'^admin/',  include(admin.site.urls)),  # admin site
)
```

A url starts with ^ and ends with $. so if $ is encountered django understands that the url has ended and there's nothing more infront of that. so in your case it will no more look for "registration". or if your url with "registration" doesnt matches to any urls specified at all.